# How to remove the second app bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, appbar, flutter-packages

I have developed a flutter package which has its own localization and theme and because of that i have used MaterialApp widget in package.

```
return MaterialApp(
  key: Key('key_root_widget'),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ChatController.chatConfig.themeData,
  locale: ChatController.chatConfig.locale,
  routes: Routes.routes,
  supportedLocales: [
    Locale('en', 'US'),
    Locale('es', 'ES'),
    Locale('da', 'DK'),
  ],
  localizationsDelegates: [
    // A class which loads the translations from JSON files
    AppLocalizations.delegate,
    // Built-in localization of basic text for Material widgets
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    // Built-in localization for text direction LTR/RTL
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    // Built-in localization of basic text for Cupertino widgets
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  // Returns a locale which will be used by the app
  localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
    // Check if the current device locale is supported
    for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
      if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode) {
        return supportedLocale;
      }
    }
    // If the locale of the device is not supported, use the first one
    // from the list (English, in this case).
    return supportedLocales.first;
  },
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flutter Package'),),
    body: Material(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: widget.controller.init(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (_chatStore.navigateToChatRoom) _navigateToChatRoom();
            return _buildBody();
          } else {
            return CustomProgressIndicatorWidget();
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

I want to remove project's app bar and only want to use package app bar but unfortunately i am unable to do that. Help needed :)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: try flutter clean and run it again

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line from your code,

```
appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flutter Package'),),
```

Comment: The question was how to remove project's app bar and not the package's. Since he is developing a package, it is not clear on how to remove the project's app bar.

Comment: I want the app bar related to package but want to hide the project's app bar (the first one).

Comment: add your complete code to show how you're using your package.

Comment: Just add your all code files in the question to find your issue.